# How to make multiple template tags work separately?

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

While working on a project on django , I came to a situation where I have to join four strings and also have to save the joined string in another variable. So, I made two custom template tag to do so.
1) for saving one data to another

```
@register.simple_tag
def save(value):
    return value
```

2)to join the strings

```
@register.simple_tag
def link(a,b,c,d):
    data=str(a)+","+str(b)+str(c)+","+str(d)
    return data
```

but when I am calling them from template like-

```
{% save link 14 12 2 3 as data %}
```

an error occurred saying--

> 'save' received too many positional arguments

that means they are overlapping each other. Now how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using one template tag, you can use two tag line by line...

- First one is for link function
- Second is for save function

`{% link 14 12 2 3 as data %}
{% save data as value %}`

Comment: Thanks @MK Patel

Comment: Happy Coding :)